# Logon scrip that kills another user's task

Tags: windows, logon-scripts

Running a Win 2016 server with one application that can only be used by one user at a time.
I have a prioritized user account on the server. When that user logs in, he should always be able to start that specific application.

My idea was to make a logon script that kills the applications task for all users. That way my prioritzed user will be able to start up the application.

I've not succeeded creating that logon script. Can anyone help me or advice me to any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check **[taskkill](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill)** command

E.g. `taskkill /im "process.exe"`

Make sure the script is running with local admin rights and in elevated mode ("Run with the highest privileges" check in Task Scheduler).

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware I could do that via Task Scheduler. That solved my issue